# Combining multiple files in proxy response

Tags: proxy, video-streaming, streaming, reverse-proxy, http2

I want to create a proxy server that automatically responds with the next video file when it detects one has ended. It can happen that within one request it needs to send information from two different endpoints.

My current solution would be to:
If it didn't detect file switching simply redirect to the correct `URL` with headers
If within the bytes range we need to get another file compute it locally and send information directly

What I'd like to know is if there is any solution, maybe involving `HTTP/2` stream prioritization, that would help me avoid computing anything locally, and I'd be able to redirect to two URLs one after another. Is it even possible with `HTTP` protocol?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the problem you're trying to solve?  And, what clients are you intending to support?  Sure, you can just keep sending stream data out there, but you'll lose the benefit of CDNs.

Comment: I want to send video ads in between the actual video dynamically. I'll know the ad URL and the range I need to send from the initial file before it. It is not a problem to combine these two if I download the given videos on the server. The problem happens if I want to just send combined data without downloading it from two resources.

Comment: For the clients, it should support every that can use URLs to grab resources.

Answer (score 0):

Form your comment it sounds like you are trying to provide in stream video advertising - i.e. a mid roll video ad/groups of ads.

There are two main approaches for ad insertion that are usually used:

- Client Side Ad Insertion (CSAI)
- Server Side Ad insertion (SSAI)

Both have their own pros and cons.

Client side relies on the player driving the request for the ad video, typically pausing he main video and requesting the ad video. The ad video will often be pre-fetched to avoid delays, and sometimes two separate players within an app may be used, one for ads and the other for the main content, the one not being used being paused and hidden. Again this is usually to avoid delay. AD insertion can be triggered by config or signalling from the server.

Server side hides this complexity from the player, with the network manipulating the video manifest to insert the ad segments. The player in theory does not know the content is switching from main video to ad, although in practice when multi period DASH, for example, is used it is relatively straightforward to observe it.

For your case it sounds like you are looking for an SSAI like approach. SSAI servers are quite specialised solutions and building your own would likely be quite an intensive task. Using an existing SSAI server would also allow you build on a standard protocol for the ad requests, i.e. VAST.

It might be good to experiment with some of the available servers to decide what best meets your needs - AWS Media Services has some good online info on server side ad insertion and you can experiment quite easily with a flow to get a feel for it:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediatailor/latest/ug/ca-setting-up-emt-ssai.topic.html

Comment: ChatGPT is that you? You can't decepticon me by transforming some phrases into your own wording... Please confirm (not a bad thing, just wondering if it played a part in making this answer)

Comment: @VC.One  No this is not ChatGPT decepticoning (sic) you. If you think something needs to be corrected in the answer let me know.